# What function can be used to set data to two decimal points?

Tags: numbers, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does Apache IoTDB now have a function that can automatically retains two decimal places for all data in time series? Or does IoTDB have a function that can set the number of decimal points I want for time series data?

Answer (score 0):

User can set the number of digital after decimal point of 'FLOAT' type data using 'float_precision' parameter in the CLI tool of Apache IoTDB.The default value of this parameter is '2'.